# GODEBUG=memprofilerate env variable not taking effect with pprof

Tags: go, profiling

ubuntu$ echo $GODEBUG
memprofilerate=1024

I set this var in my bashrc. But still when I do heap profiling only allocs > 512kb are seen in top command. What am I missing?

More outputs:

```
ubuntu$ env | grep '^GODEBUG='
GODEBUG=memprofilerate=1024
ubuntu$ env | grep '^GODEBUG=' | xxd
00000000: 474f 4445 4255 473d 6d65 6d70 726f 6669  GODEBUG=memprofi
00000010: 6c65 7261 7465 3d31 3032 340a            lerate=1024.
```

Edit: This is a long running process running over 4 days. The linux top -p  command is showing a steady increase in memory used by this process but pprof is not able to catch newly allocated space.

Last 2 profile collections:
Jul 26 2pm : Top shows used KiB mem - 3145692. pprof profile heap1.out
Jul 28 7pm : Top shows used KiB mem - 3915992. pprof profile heap2.out

go tool pprof of heap1.out and heap2.out show the same top 27 inuse_space numbers.

Comment: Yes. ubuntu$ echo $GODEBUG memprofilerate=1024

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski edited